# Struggling to pick up MVVM Basics

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am brand new to MVVM (some experience with WPF) and I am getting really confused with regards to what I assume as the basics. I'm trying to make a simple registration form. The user enters their name, a username and a password. For the sake of learning MVVM and not over-complicating things, the only check I am doing on the password is if it contains an upper case letter. No hashing, encryption etc.. for now.

So I have a model that is a `User`, generated from entity framework. Here is my first bit of confusion. It looks like so:

```
public partial class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (_firstName == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's in a little bit of a mismatch. The first section was generated by Entity, which I have modified with regards to the FirstName to look like what I believe is more MVVM. Is the Model the location where I create get/set, do they also need to be in the ViewModel?

Moving onto my ViewModel, I am confused as to whether or not I need to recreate the properties of the `User` (FirstName, LastName ....) again, or are they accessible through the Model. Can I create a `User` in the ViewModel that exposes all of the properties of a `User`? Here is the code for my `ViewModel` so far:

```
internal class NewUserViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private User _newUser;
    public User NewUser
    {
        get => _newUser;
        set
        {
            if (_newUser == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _newUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NewUser");
        }
    }

    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get => _password;
        set
        {
            if (_password == value)
                return;
            _password = value;
            OnPasswordChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    #region RegisterCommand

    private DelegateCommand _registerCommand;
    public ICommand RegisterCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _registerCommand = new DelegateCommand(param => Register(), param => CanRegister());
            return _registerCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanRegister()
    {
        return _isPasswordValid;
    }

    private bool _isPasswordValid;
    public void OnPasswordChanged()
    {
        _isPasswordValid = Password.Any(char.IsUpper);
    }

    private void Register()
    {
        using (var context = new WorkstreamContext())
        {
            var users = context.Set<User>();
            users.Add(_newUser);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

As of now I have recreated the `Password` property so I can access it, however this settles uneasily for me and I feel like I either expose all the properties or use `NewUser`, however I am unsure about how to do this. Currently the code half works. The `Save` button is grayed out, however it does not become enabled when the password contains an uppercase letter which is what I would expect. The actual registration form:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/NewUserForm/NewUser.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Please Enter Your Details" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="DarkSlateGray" FontSize="16"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=FirstNameTextBox}" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/NewUserForm/FirstName.jpg" Margin="5,5,0,5"/>
        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="FirstNameTextBox" Watermark="first name" Text="{Binding NewUser.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LastNameTextBox}" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/NewUserForm/LastName.jpg" Margin="5,5,0,5"/>
        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="LastNameTextBox"  Watermark="last name" Text="{Binding NewUser.LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="4">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=UsernameTextBox}" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/NewUserForm/User.jpg" Margin="5,5,0,5"/>
        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="UsernameTextBox"  Watermark="username" Text="{Binding NewUser.Username, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=PasswordTextBox}" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/NewUserForm/Password.jpg" Margin="5,5,0,5"/>
        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PasswordTextBox"  Watermark="password" Text="{Binding NewUser.Password, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="6">
        <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource NewUserViewModel}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Is the way that I have bound the TextBoxes to the NewUser exposed on the ViewModel the correct way to operate in MVVM? I appreciate that there are ALOT of tutorials on MVVM, I have read/viewed many. However, I am getting to the stage where I am feeling more and more confused, and would really appreciate if someone would give me a breakdown on my code and pointers on where I am going wrong, why the code is not working and where I can improve.

Comment: I would not mix the EF and UI classes like `User`. I recommend using two classes instead: one for the DB and one for the UI like a `UserViewModel`.

Comment: Exactly what the first comment says - you are mixing up concerns. The M in MVVM/MVC is for a POCO (or POCO with a binding glue) representing data that the View presents to the user in any given context. The EF class you are talking about is in the DAL, in the specific bounded domain.

Comment: What I would recommend is looking in to an MVVM framework Like MVVMLite, Caliburn or Prism. Prism is extremely well [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430857(v=pandp.40).aspx) and I recommend looking into it.

Comment: Also the reason you password is not working is because you are not notifying anyone of change you need to do RegisterCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); and also create _registerCommand only once not every time a property is called. You can look into [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921082(v=pandp.40).aspx)

Comment: Also, the password textbox is binding to the NewUser.Password so when you are checking the password, you are checking the Password property in the view model, which is different to the NewUser.Password and so will never get set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad. But if the `User` class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, it is effectively a kind of a view model and you can bind directly to the properties of this one like you are doing:

```
{Binding NewUser.FirstName}
```

If `NewUser` was some kind of DTO object, you could wrap it in your view model and bind to the view model properties:

```
public string Password
{ 
    get { return _user.Password; }
    set { return _user.Password = value; OnNotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

A real "model" is rather a service or some kind of business logic object.

> The Save button is grayed out, however it does not become enabled when the password contains an uppercase letter which is what I would expect.

Does the setter of your `Password` property even get hit? Bind to the `Password` property *of the view model*:

```
Text="{Binding Password}"
```

...and call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` of the command to refresh its status:

```
private string _password;
public string Password
{
    get => _password;
    set
    {
        if (_password == value)
            return;
        _password = value;
        OnPasswordChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("Password");

        _registerCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); //<--
    }
}
```